win32 SDL2(SDLRenderer2) + Imgui IME text input composition
Im using SDL2 + ImGUI.
When using Win32 as platform and Dx11 as renderer,
InputText shows current composing charaacter like below image.

But when using SDL2 + SDLRenderer2,
It doesn't shows korean character "안" while composing,
but it shows "안" only after composing character completed.
Im not sure it is Win32 and WindowMesasge thing,
Im looking at WinProc functions in Imgui and SDL2,
but Im not sure about what's going on here.
I tryied
SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_IME_SHOW_UI, "1");
SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_IME_INTERNAL_EDITING, "1");

but It doesn't work.
when using SDL2 + dx11,
it doesn't shows composing character too.
It looks like
SDL_windowskeyboard.c
WIN_SetTextInputRect()
is called correctly, but still IME compositionForm is not showing.
I checked that ImmSetCompositionWindow() is called correctly,
but it doesn't work for some reason.
